# Get string from a base64 encoded string in python

Tags: python

I have to make a post to a rest server in python. In header authentication I have to include a base64 encoded string.

I do it with base64 module:

```
import base64
#node here is '3180' but I also tried with text
node = base64.b64encode(node.encode('utf-8'))
node = 'Basic ' + str(node)
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Authentication': node}
print(headers)
```

And what I get in print is:

```
{'Authentication': "Basic b'MzE4MA=='", 'Content-type': 'application/json'}
```

Which has `b' ... '` added to node base64 string. Is there a way to avoid those characters to appear? I don't know if they just appears in prints or also are sent to the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`b64encode` is returning `bytes` instead of a `str`. When you call `str()` on it without specifying an encoding, instead of converting the value, it's actually giving you the Python representation of the bytes object which is `b'MzE4MA=='`.

To avoid this use `node = 'Basic ' + node.decode('ascii')`

Note that you could also use `str(node, encoding='ascii')` but this is longer.